# How to select last 7 days available - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am having problem with dealing with data in MySQL. How can I select all data from the pasty seven available data?

I tried to run

```
SELECT * FROM database where ship_day 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW();
```

but I doesn't work for my purpose.
Let's say we are on January, 9th and my `MAX(ship_day)` is January, 7th and I want to pull data from the past 7 available data so from January 1st to 7th.

I tried to run

```
SELECT * FROM database where ship_day 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(MAX(ship_day), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND MAX(ship_day);
```

but I got an error.

I know that I can increase `INTERVAL 7 DAY` to `INTERVAL 9 DAY` but I want this process to be automatic. How can I solve?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is one method:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM database d 
WHERE d.ship_day >= COALESCE( (SELECT DISTINCT d2.ship_day 
                               FROM database d2 
                               ORDER BY d2.ship_day DESC
                               LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6
                              ), d.ship_day
                           );
```

Note:  If you have only one row per `ship_day`, then just use `limit`:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM database d 
ORDER BY d.ship_day DESC
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say we are on January, 9th and my MAX(ship_day) is January, 7th
>   and I want to pull data from the past 7 available data so from January
>   1st to 7th.

I assume you are looking for the query below but hard to say for sure without example data and expected results.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 t
WHERE
 ship_day >= (
   SELECT 
     MAX(ship_day) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   FROM
    t
 )
```

Or you can also write this as

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 t
WHERE
 ship_day >= (
   SELECT 
     MAX(ship_day)
   FROM
    t
 ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: *"works! but the one from gordon linoff is faster "* Yes @LucaFerrario this will most likely need to scan the whole table data or index data for the inner query that's true.. But i assume `ship_day ` column is indexed in your table?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last date for which you have data with:

```
select MAX(ship_day) FROM database
```

so use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM database 
where ship_day >= DATE_SUB((select MAX(ship_day) FROM database), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```